# How to trigger middle mouse button using vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm writing a test for a tab component that should close the tab via an x icon and also via middle mouse button click. The test for the x icon is no problem but I have a hard time triggering this middle mouse button event.

I would have expected it to work with this:

```
wrapper.find('.tab').trigger('click', { button: 1 });
```

Also tried:

```
wrapper.find('.tab').trigger('click.middle');
```

The found component is not an issue. For testing purpose I hooked the close functionality to the normal click event and with that the test succeeds.

Could it be related to how I implemented the middle click on the tab component?
That is done like this:

```
<div class="tab"
    @mousedown.prevent @click.middle="close()"
[...]
</div>
```

Any clue how that would work? The documentation does not go into detail about that topic.

Comment: I tried this on the [getting started repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-getting-started) and it appears to work both ways but adding the option `button: 1` was the only way to prevent all clicks being captured.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when testing for a component that had multiple mouse events on the same element. In order to test for @click.middle I had to trigger a 'mouseup' event.

Try this:

```
wrapper.find('.tab').trigger('mouseup', { button: 1 })
```